# Is it possible to do replication of only one table with different mysql databases in different hosts?

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I'm trying to do replication of one table in a remote host in my database. Suppose there is a change in the remote database and i want it commited or replicated to my database in order to keep it up to date with the lastest changes without having to run any dumps, cron scripts or something similar. Is there any way to replicate only one table from a remote database into a table inside the database in the host that i'm working with? By the way, i'm using mysql databases in a freebsd based systems both places.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use FEDERATED engine (possibly coupled with event scheduler to update your local table)

Comment: sounds like a great workaround, but we want to avoid to deal with slow cable issues from remote server and still preserve innodb storage engine, but thanks for provide info about other storage engines :)

Comment: finally we did a create table and federate with a user with only write permission, i know this answer was a little bit forgotten, excuse me i was trying to do all my job pile all this long, i will mark you answer as the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering this in order to help persons who may end up here searching.

You can use MySQL Replication with replicate-wild-do-table configuration option to get this done.